Showing that an optimum $x^*$ is a local minimizer

Consider $$f(x_1,x_2)=x_1^2+x_2e^{x_1}-x_1x_2+x_2^2,$$ Show that $ x^*
= (0, -\frac12 ) $is a local minimizer.

Definition
A point $ x^* $ is a local minimizer if there is a neighborhood $\mathcal{N}$ of $x^*$ such that $f (x^*) \le f (x)$ for $x \in \mathcal{N}$.
Consider,
$f(x_1,x_2)=x_1^2+x_2e^{x_1}-x_1x_2+x_2^2,$
then, \begin{equation}
    \nabla f(x_1,x_2)= \begin{pmatrix}
        2x_1+x_2e^{x_1}-x_2\\
        -x_1+e^{x_1}+2x_2
    \end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation}
Then the Hessian is :
\begin{equation}
   \nabla^2f(x_1,x_2)= \begin{pmatrix}
        2+x_2e^{x_1}\\
        2
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Insert for the point $x^*=(0,-\frac12) $ in the Hessian and obtain:
\begin{equation}
   \nabla^2f(0,-\frac12)= \begin{pmatrix}
        2-\frac12e^{0}\\
        2
    \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        -\frac32\\
        2
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
However, the latter is not positive definite, since there is one negative eigenvalue. Why is the proposed local minimum therefore not satisfying positive definitivity of the Hessian?
Thanks

The Hessian is a 2 by 2 matrix.  You haven’t computed it correctly.

@BrianBorchers Still I get eigenvalues which are of mixed sign.
\begin{equation}
\nabla^2f(0,-\frac12)= \begin{pmatrix}
2-\frac12e^{0} & 0\
2 & 2
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
-\frac32 & 0\
2 & 2
\end{pmatrix} \end{equation}. $\lambda_{1,2}=-\frac32, 2$

The Hessian matrix should be symmetric, so again you've computed it incorrectly.

@BrianBorchers. I recomputed it on paper. Got the same result. This problem does not make complete sense, because the other condition that $\nabla  f(x^* )=0$ for having a local minimizer does also not hold.

@Superunknown The Hessian is $$\begin{pmatrix}
2 + x_2 \mathrm{e}^{x_1} & \mathrm{e}^{x_1} - 1 \
\mathrm{e}^{x_1} - 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Thanks River Li, your Hessian confirms that my comments with the Hessian calculations to Brian are correct too.

@Superunknown In my comment, $$H(0, -1/2) = \begin{pmatrix}  3/2 & 0 \  0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}.$$ What is yours?

@Superunknown By the way, you may use @, otherwise, I may not receive notifications for your comment.

@RiverLi thanks you are right!
